# Sometimes HLS chunks does not generate in /tmp/hls directory

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, rtmp, http-live-streaming

I am working on an adaptive HLS solution using Nginx RTMP module as a streaming server and VideoJs as a client. I have completed the setup i.e. NGINX configurations and client sample in VideoJs.

NGINX Configurations:
[nginx.txt](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/files/2118055/nginx.txt)

I am using this Ffmpeg command to generate stream:

```
ffmpeg -re -i /home/user/Downloads/test.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -vprofile baseline -g 30 -acodec aac -strict -2 -f flv rtmp://192.168.1.68/live
```

My problem is that sometimes the Nginx does not generate .ts and .m3u8 files in `/tmp/hls` directory when I issue the above ffmpeg command. I have also enabled the nginx-rtmp module logs but they are only giving me access information and I am not getting any logs in error logs.

Do let me know if more information is required. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried doing it yourself without Nginx?